# How to add an external javascript file into a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a react component (jsx) which shows a forum and few images , I have also a button who shows a popup or modal but this popup is programmed with JavaScript in an external file.
I want to load this code into my component.
I used a script tag and didn't work. any ideas ?
this is my external JavaScript file :

```
let popup = document.getElementById('popup');
let modalContainer = document.getElementById('modal-container');
let buttonTarget = document.getElementById('button-target');
let cross = document.getElementById('cross');


buttonTarget.addEventListener('click', openModal);
cross.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

   function openModal() {
    popup.style.display = 'block';
    modalContainer.style.display = 'block';
  }

  function closeModal() {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
    modalContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: There is no React at all in your code

Comment: no this is my external file js

Comment: And your React component?

Comment: can you show your React component ?

Comment: it's huge my friend

Answer (score 0):

React is also Javascript (jsx is another way/syntax of writing javascript code which then transpiles to javascript) so You can use any javascript file within it. In order to do that first check that javascript file exports what You want to use in Your react component then check if You imported it in the file which holds react component.

Answer (score 0):

It can could be done adding `<script>` tag in your html. 
But javascript code which manipulates DOM isn't advised to be used along with React. Also Modals or Popups can easily handled by react state.
And you can find several libraries as well. 
for ex, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

Answer (score 0):

Lets Say Your External JS file is  `Temp.js` containing the following piece of code or a function .

```
export function foo(){
 //some code here}
```

For meeting the current situation you move|copy that file to same folder where your component is

now simply add this to your component

```
import {foo} from "./temp";
```

here you go you have imported the file

Now How to use that as it is the function

so call this as simply  `foo()`

Comment: If You want to access  this file from anywhere in your react app thn you can use script tag in the index.html file in the react app and you can access this by window.foo()

Comment: didn't work 
look at my function in my js file in the updated question

Comment: Code in ur file can be easily done in your react component with easily logic